# Prolog Json handle

Tags: json, prolog

```
server():- http_server(http_dispatch, [port(45000)]).

serverTest(Request):-http_read_json(Request, JSONIn),
  json_to_prolog(JSONIn, PrologIn), format(PrologIn) .
```

I have this Prolog program but I can't handle the PrologIn variable very well. I get this error:

```
Type error: `text' expected, found `json([id=3])'
```

I know that means I can't use *format* with *PrologIn* but how do I handle the information inside? Meaning, how do I extract the "id = 3" info ?

**Edit:**

This is the full program

(If I use more than enough modules, is because I'm doing other stuff with the program and didn't filtered to this specific case)

```
:- use_module(library(http/thread_httpd)). 
:- use_module(library(http/http_dispatch)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_parameters)). 
:- use_module(library(http/http_ssl_plugin)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_open)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_client)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_json)).
:- use_module(library(http/json)).

:- http_handler('/test', serverTest, []).
```

**The rest is the first two predicts before the edit**

I test this by first going on the Prolog's console and typing "server().", this starts the server. Then I use Postman in the following way: Select **POST**, in the Headers the key is *Content-Type* and its value is *application/json*, then, in the Body, I select **raw** (JSON(application-json)) and write this in the text area:

```
{
  "id" : 3
}
```

This is how I test it, I want to be able to handle the id=3 information in the prolog predicate (serverTest).

Comment: Please tell us how we can reproduce anything you are seeing. For example, how to invoke the program etc.

Comment: What do you mean "handle the id=3"? What are you going to do with it? This is important, because at that point it would be easiest to reply with back with a JSON, and there are perfectly good examples how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your Prolog web library, but I'm guessing `http_read_json` already binds its second argument to a Prolog term so the the call to `json_to_prolog` is unnecessary and incorrect.

Try

```
serverTest(Request) :- http_read_json(Request, JSONIn), format(JSOnIn).
```

If you want to isolate the id number from what you receive, this could be as simple as

```
serverTest(Request) :- http_read_json(Request, json([id=X])),
     % ... do something with X value here ... %
```

Comment: I tried both cases. Neither worked. Either way, I edited the question with the full code and further description.

Answer (score 4):

You really need to show the full program, how you start the server, and how you query it. Otherwise, one can only guess.

Anyway, few problems with this: `format(PrologIn)`.

First, as the program tells you, this is a term. And `format` does formatted output. At the very least, you would have to write:

```
format("~w", [PrologIn])
```

See the [documentation on `format/2`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=format), basically, if your term looks like this: `json([id=3])`, you should get `json([id=3])` printed.

Now the next question: where would this print to? When you start a server with the HTTP package libraries, input and output are redirected so that you can read requests and write responses. There are *many* examples in the library documentation.

Then the next thing: how you get the 3 out of there. If you additionally load the [http_json plugin module](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=httpjson):

```
:- use_module(library(http/http_json)).
```

then you can directly use, as shown in the code example,

```
http_read_json_dict(Request, DictIn)
```

Now `DictIn` is a "dict" probably looking like this: `_{id:3}`. See the [documentation on dicts](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=dicts).

You don't *have to* use dicts, just inspect the `json` term using normal pattern matching and list processing. Dicts are just easier (as in, less typing) for some use cases.

### Edit

Here is a **minimal example** that works for me. This is the server code:

```
:- use_module(library(http/thread_httpd)). 
:- use_module(library(http/http_dispatch)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_json)).

:- http_handler('/test', test, []).

server :-
    http_server(http_dispatch, [port(45000)]).

test(Request) :-
    http_read_json_dict(Request, JSON),
    format(user_error, "~w~n", [JSON.id]).
```

From the top level, after consulting the file, I run:

```
?- server.
% Started server at http://localhost:45000/
true.
```

At that point, I use curl from another command line like this:

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":3}' http://localhost:45000/test
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

and I get the 3 printed out on the Prolog toplevel where the server is running:

```
?- 3
```

This is of course not ideal, so I replace the last line in the server code with the following:

```
reply_json(_{foobar:JSON.id}).
```

and then on the Prolog toplevel, where the server is running, I use `make/0`:

```
?- make.
% Updating index for library .../lib/swipl-7.3.35/library/
% ... compiled 0.00 sec, 0 clauses
true.
```

Now, when I again use curl:

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":3}' http://localhost:45000/test
{"foobar":3}
```

This is all you need!

Comment: @PedroGonçalves See the edited answer. I figured this out by reading the documentation!